# Stubbing pg-promise using sinon and mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, pg-promise, sinon-chai

Suppose I have a the following module, as database.js

```
const initOptions = {}
const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions)
const config = require('../../config')

const db = pgp({
  host: config.database.host,
  port: config.database.port,
  database: config.database.database,
  user: config.database.user,
  password: config.database.password
})

module.exports = db
```

And the following module as create.js

```
const db = require('./database')

function create (name) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.func('create', name)
      .then(data => {
        return resolve(data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return reject(err)
      })
  })
}

module.exports = create
```

I'm trying to run a unit test on create.js that will test that db.func is called with 'create' as first argument and 'name' as the second, but without actually needing to set up a database connection (So tests can run offline).

From what I can gather, this is what libraries like sinon.JS can be used for, so I tried creating a test and stubbed the db object.

```
const chai = require('chai')
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised')

chai.use(chaiAsPromised)

const sinon = require('sinon')

const expect = chai.expect

const create = require('./create.js')

describe('Test Module', () => {
  it('should test stuff', () => {
    const db = require('./database')
    const dbStub = sinon.stub(db, 'func').callsFake(Promise.resolve(null))
    expect(create('test').then).to.be.a('Function')
  })
})
```

However, it fails with

```
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: func
```

Most likely due to my limited exposure to sinon...

How do I go about stubbing (or maybe I need to mock?) the db function so that I can test it an ensure db.func was called?

Comment: The property `func` of that object is not configurable, that means `sinon` can't replace the property with `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: That's also what I could figure out from researching it.

However, I'm looking to see if there's any other way to do this with pg-promise. It simply cannot be true that you can't do offline unit tests with pg-promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the properties configurable by disabling locks with the no `noLocking` option in [Initialization Options](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/module-pg-promise.html). This allows sinon to replace the properties:

```
const initOptions = { noLocking : true };
```

On a related note:

Your `create` function is creating an unnecessary promise wrapper, which is a promise anti-pattern. You should just return the result from `db.func`, which is a promise already:

```
function create(name) {
      return db.func('create', name);
}
```

Also `callsFake` takes a function and you are giving it a promise. Use `returns` instead:

```
const dbStub = sinon.stub(db, 'func').returns(Promise.resolve(null))
```

> I'm having trouble setting the `noLocking` option. The docs state it can be set after initialization, however if I set it with `db.$config.options.noLocking = true`, the same error occurs. However, if I set it in the database.js init options it works fine.

From the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)...

It is because at that point the `noLocking` can only affect tasks and transactions. And since the `db` level of the protocol is initiated only once, setting `noLocking` after the library's initialization doesn't effect it.

I have just updated the [documentation](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/module-pg-promise.html) to clarify it:

`This option is dynamic (can be set before or after initialization). However, changing it after the library's initialization will not affect Database objects that have already been created.`

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like the right solution!

however, I'v having trouble setting the noLocking option. The docs state it can be set after initialization, however if I set it with db.$config.options.noLocking = true, the same error occurs.

However, if I set it in the database.js init options it works fine. Though, seting it in the database.js module wouldn't be optimal. any idea?

Comment: @MadsRC, I have no idea to be honest, I think it's unlikely you can set that option like that. Once the object is set to non-configurable there's no way anyone can reset it to configurable.

Comment: @MadsRC, what you could do is only add the option to your init options if your ENV is development.  That way you can still lock it while in production.

Comment: That was what I did actually!

Though even though I stub db.func to return Promise.resolve(nulll) (As you advised) in the test, when I call create, the db function actually still connects to the database and creates (I happened to have a database listening on localhost as I was testing). Is that expected behaviour, or should sinon.stub not overwrite the db.func referenced in create.js ?